# Is it possible to connect a standard resolution Laptop to an external HD Display LED Monitor?

Tags: led, laptop-display

I am having an Acer Aspire 5920 notebook with the following details:

Display resolution:

```
Display: 15.4" Acer CrystalBrite TFT LCD, WXGA (220-nit), 1280 x 800 Resolution
```

Port for External Display:

```
VGA port (External display)
```

I want to connect this Laptop to an external LED Monitor with HD - Display.

I am confused about the compatibility issues (since the Laptop screen provides a lower resolution display).

Can somebody please guide me on what parameters to check in this case?

(I want to use External Display as the Primary Display)

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As long as your laptop video card supports external monitor (and it does, it has external VGA), you'll be fine. Resolution is mostly limitation of a screen, not video-card.

And to make external monitor a primary, you'll need to make it primary monitor in monitor settings (presuming you are on Windows OS).

Comment: Thanks. I am a pure GNU/Linux user. I will figure out how to make the external display as primary in GNU/Linux.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't find it right, so this is edit with `Intel® GMA X3100`

Tech Specs from Intel states

> Max. resolution stated as 2048x1536

These shoud also provide you with suffice resolution for all common LCD Monitors on market.

Resource:
http://download.intel.com/products/graphics/intel_graphics_guide.pdf

Comment: According to [Acer Support: Aspire 5920 Series Specifications](http://support.acer.com/acerpanam/notebook/0000/Acer/Aspire5920/Aspire5920sp2.shtml), the notebook has a Mobile Intel® GM965 Express Chipset.

Comment: Yes, I have an Intel Graphics card. The graphic card details are as follows: "Graphics Card: Mobile Intel GM965 Express Chipset with Intel Graphics Media Accelerator X3100 with up to 358MB Shared Graphics"